# Python (Telegram bot) | json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot

Здраствуйте. Возникла проблема с функцией телеграм бота.

Принцип работы предельно прост: пользователь отправляет запрос и получает в ответ сообщение с изображением, которое загружается на Telegraph. Фрагмент кода упрощен от всех лишних деталей, так что тут нужно просто получить текстовый путь к этому файлу.

Основная проблема заключается в том, что задача выполняется через раз. Т.е., в один раз все происходит как требуется, в другой же возникает ошибка, код ошибки представлен ниже. Возможно это проблема связанна с самими запросами к Telegraph, который ограничивает их количество.

Пробовал выполнять различные манипуляции, предложенные в этой статье https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0 , но не пришел к решению.

Буду благодарен если поможете разобраться с природой ошибки, за совет или же за помощь в решении самой проблемы.

**Основной код:**

```python
from telegraph import Telegraph
import json
import requests

telegraph = Telegraph()
telegraph.create_account(short_name='nick')
with open("image.jpg", 'rb') as f:
    path = requests.post('https://telegra.ph/upload', files={'file': ('file', f, 'image/jpg')}).json()[0]['src']
    print(path)
```

**Правильный результат (пример):**

```
/file/38ff935665107f3c8fb99.jpg
```

**Ошибка:**

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Выведите через print что приходит в `requests.post(...).text`. Судя по ошибке, там не json.

Comment: Вообще, желательно разделить запрос и получение результата из него, и в ответе проверять код результата, что он 200 или 201, или делать `response.raise_for_status()`, чтобы вылетало исключение, если запрос не успешен.

Comment: Несколько раз нажал запрос. В первом случае приходит: <html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.20.1</center>
</body>
</html>

Во втором: [{"src":"\/file\/12315d6f37fbb6280989f.jpg"}]

Comment: Ну вот когда 500 ошибка приходит у вас и вылетает ошибка, что не может распарсить json. Так что нужно проверять статус как я во втором комментарии написал.

Comment: А вы не могли бы подсказать, как правильно сформировать это исключение исходя из этой ситуации?

Comment: Хотя, вроде справился.
retries = 3

                for n in range(retries):
                    try:
                        response = requests.post('https://telegra.ph/upload', files={'file': ('file', f, 'image/jpg')})
                        response.raise_for_status()

                        break

                    except HTTPError as exc:
                        code = exc.response.status_code

                        if code in [429, 500, 502, 503, 504]:
                            time.sleep(2)
                            continue

                        raise

Comment: Можете добавить свой ответ, я отмечу его, как верный. Спасибо Вам большое :)

Comment: Там еще внутри находится:                     if response.status_code == 200:
                        response = response.json()[0]['src']

Что ж, вроде, проблем более не возникает. Вы действительно хороший специалист, еще раз благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ основан на советах пользователя [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor) за что ему безмерная благодарность.

```
from telegraph import Telegraph
import json
import requests

from requests.exceptions import HTTPError # для обработки исключений

telegraph = Telegraph()
telegraph.create_account(short_name='nick')
retries = 3 # Кол-во попыток для запроса

# Цикл для корректного выполнения запроса к Telegraph
for n in range(retries):
    try:
        with open(image.jpg, 'rb') as f:
            response = requests.post('https://telegra.ph/upload', files={'file': ('file', f, 'image/jpg')}) # Выполнение запроса
            response.raise_for_status() # Получение информации о коде состояния HTTP

        # Если статус код состояния HTTP "200", то выполняется получение результата из него
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response = response.json()[0]['src']

        break

    # Если код состояния HTTP не "200" и соответствует значению в переменной code, то после задержки в 2 секунды, выполняется новая попытка совершения запроса
    except HTTPError as exc:
        code = exc.response.status_code

        if code in [429, 500, 502, 503, 504]:
            time.sleep(2)
            continue

        raise

    print(response)
```